How to forward GUI display inside a container to docker running in WSL and eventually forwarded to XMing on Windows?
I have a docker engine running inside WSL2, and if I run xeyes inside a docker container, it will not display in Windows
Is it possible to forward display from container > WSL2 > Windows?
I can run a GUI app like xeyes within WSL2 and it opens in Windows with Xming.
